# SQL query is executed on web hosting with error but on localhost it runs without a problem

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I want to upload my project online. Recently I've bought web hosting service and I've already checked the version of my and their server - 10.1.38-MariaDB. The following query runs without a problem on my localhost database server, but when I tried to run it online I'm getting the following error, why?

## 1005 - Can't create table `psyclade_project`.`companies` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Obviously the problem is the foreign keys, how could I fix it?

The query is:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------
-- Host:                         127.0.0.1
-- Server version:               10.1.38-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
-- Server OS:                    Win64
-- HeidiSQL Version:             10.2.0.5607
-- --------------------------------------------------------

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;

-- Dumping structure for table dev.companies
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `companies` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `owner_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_8244AA3A5E237E06` (`name`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_8244AA3A7E3C61F9` (`owner_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_8244AA3A7E3C61F9` FOREIGN KEY (`owner_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- Data exporting was unselected.

-- Dumping structure for table dev.jobs
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jobs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `author_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `createdOn` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_A8936DC5F675F31B` (`author_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_A8936DC5F675F31B` FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- Data exporting was unselected.

-- Dumping structure for table dev.roles
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `roles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_B63E2EC75E237E06` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- Data exporting was unselected.

-- Dumping structure for table dev.schools
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `schools` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_47443BD55E237E06` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- Data exporting was unselected.

-- Dumping structure for table dev.users
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `school_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `full_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ages` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_1483A5E9F85E0677` (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_1483A5E9E7927C74` (`email`),
  KEY `IDX_1483A5E9C32A47EE` (`school_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_1483A5E9C32A47EE` FOREIGN KEY (`school_id`) REFERENCES `schools` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- Data exporting was unselected.

-- Dumping structure for table dev.users_roles
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_roles` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `role_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`role_id`),
  KEY `IDX_51498A8EA76ED395` (`user_id`),
  KEY `IDX_51498A8ED60322AC` (`role_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_51498A8EA76ED395` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_51498A8ED60322AC` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `roles` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- Data exporting was unselected.

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=IFNULL(@OLD_SQL_MODE, '') */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=IF(@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS IS NULL, 1, @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS) */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
```

Comment: I think that problem due to database engines so please check database engines ?

Comment: Works for me - [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cMVxe5VvBwvyxbfB7xKyjf/0)

Comment: Make sure the code in the comments is executed. Especially this: `/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;`

Comment: How could I make myself sure that the code in the comments had been executed successfully? Can't I get rid of them and just write on the top FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0? Wouldn't it work?

Comment: `SET SESSION FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` on the top and `SET SESSION FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;` at the end should work. I don't know, why a server could ignore the code in the comments. There might be some settings. How do you execute the script?

Comment: Yeah, there is such an option.It's already enabled, but the error still appears.I haven't tried the code above yet.You could look at: https://prnt.sc/qhyify and https://prnt.sc/qhyj5c

Comment: I added the code you offered, but no change after all.

Comment: Seems that you are using the SQL tab in phpMyAdmin. I guess phpmyadmin is ignoring those comments. I would use the "Import" tab and just upload the file.

Comment: Great!, we're catching up, a little progress...it says 14 queries were executed successfully instead of nothing, but yet...same error.I really dunno what the heck is going on, what if we disable the foreign key checks?As far as I see it stops due to the given error.If I disable/remove all these checks wouldn't it work? Pic: https://prnt.sc/qhymii

Comment: I've tested your dump in the phpmyadmin demo. You have to **uncheck** the "check foreign keys" box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute this dump using the SQL tab in phpMyAdmin, you have to **uncheck** the "Enable foreign key checks" box, which you will find near the "Go" button.

[image]